# Is there any queue-like database which can handle concurrency well?

Tags: python, database, amazon-ec2, web-scraping

I have a server whose job is downloading web pages by given urls. It consistently receives urls from multiple servers in the same cluster. To build this, I'm thinking using a queue-like database to receive urls sent from different servers and the database should also handle the concurrency for sure. Other servers keep feeding urls to the database, and the program on this server will grab these urls in order then download the webpages.
Is there any queue-like database can do the job? Or should I have a better design insteading using queue-like database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a database for this task, I would suggest to use a message queue. Other servers can post requests on a queue and the downloading server can process tasks from the queue, one at a time and in the order that the requests were posted.

I would suggest that you look at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) since it is easy to get started with. Since you have tagged this question with 'python', perhaps [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is worth looking into as well.

Comment: RabbitMQ is massively scalable and will outperform any "Database Queue" many times over

Comment: @ErlVolton Thanks for the idea. Have you ever used SQS which is the amazon simply queue service? If so, which one is better compared to RabbitMQ or Celery? I'm using ec2 server now.

Comment: I would use SQS just because it matches the scenery...   If I had to choose between Celery and RabbitMQ, I would definitely go with RabbitMQ

Comment: @ErlVolton I read the tutorial of celery. It uses RabbitMQ as a broker.

Comment: To be honest, I recommended RMQ because I've used it before to great success and I know nothing about celery...  I checked out their page and indeed RabbitMQ is one of their supported brokers.  I also noticed that AdRoll is using them.  AdRoll does real-time-bidding and their requirements are pretty insane, so if they're using Celery it can't be all bad.  Give it a shot!